# can't get hadoop to see snappy

Tags: hadoop, rhel, snappy

i'm on rhel7 64bit. I managed to apparently build the hadoop 2.4.1 distribution from source. before that, i built snappy from source and installed it. then i build the hadoop dist. with

```
mvn clean install -Pdist,native,src -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Drequire.snappy
```

yet when i look at `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` i see hdfs and hadoop libs but not snappy. so when i run `hadoop checknative` it says that i don't have snappy installed. furthermore, i downloaded hadoop-snappy, and compiled /that/ and it generated the snappy libs. i copied those over to $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native /and/ to $HADOOP_HOME/lib just for extra measure. STILL, `hadoop checknative` doesn't see it!

Answer (score 0):

found the non-obvious solution in an obscure place http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Issue-with-loading-the-Snappy-Codec-td3910039.html

needed to add  `-Dcompile.native=true`. this was not highlighted in the apache build doc nor was it in any build guide i've come across!